# HDF5 in python: reading file

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I have used this before with no problem, and it suddenly doesn't work:

```
import scipy.io
import numpy as np
import h5py
f = h5py.File('Dv25.mat','r')
D = f["Dv25"]
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/jonathan/Documents/Forskning/P1/Datab/Felles/Matart/Felles/datab.py", line 5, in 
<module>
    D = f["Dv25"]
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\group.py", line 264, in __getitem__
    oid = h5o.open(self.id, self._e(name), lapl=self._lapl)
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py\h5o.pyx", line 190, in h5py.h5o.open
KeyError: "Unable to open object (object 'Dv25' doesn't exist)"
```

However, typing f gives:

```
>>> f
<HDF5 file "Dv25.mat" (mode r)>
```

and exchanging Dv25.mat for Dv25 or using either ' or " doesn't help.

What's the reason for this problem and how can I fix it? Clearly this file is "there"

Thanks!!!

Best, J

Comment: I have no experience with this library, but the problem is within python. You are trying to index something of the object "file", and the object "file" cannot be indexed. Most likely you need to transform the f into some other object that can be indexed if you want to use indexing.

Comment: Searched a little on google, try running `f.keys()` to see what can be accessed and not

Comment: So, I copied a previous code I used with success, and it worked fine for the same type of file. f.keys gave >>> f.keys
<bound method MappingHDF5.keys of <HDF5 file "Dv25.mat" (mode r)>>
So I still think my initial code should be fine...

Answer (score 0):

Some h5py/HDF5 basics:
`f` is a file object.
`f['Dv25']` is an object reference (either a group or dataset). In this case, it is a node named 'Dv25' at the root level ('/'). Apparently an object by this name doesn't exist in your file.
Use `f.keys()` to get objects at the root level.
This will return a view of the root level objects; they could be groups or data sets. You can iterate on them to get the names. To print, use this loop: (that should identify the root level names):

```
for i in f.keys():  
    print (i)
```

Note: .mat extensions usually come from Matlab, which has an option to write HDF5 formatted files. Be sure this is written in that format.

Comment: I solved it. It turned out that the output from f.keys was wrong, which I figured out from going back and checking how I generated the files in Matlab. Thanks!